# Bokeh vbar with group counts after filtering with a CDSView

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I would like to create a Bokeh vertical bar chart (`vbar`) coupled with a scatter plot. I need to start from a given `ColumnDataSource` (then filtered with a `CDSView`), as this is only a part of a complex visualization and I need all the plots to be linked together.

The only tricky part for which I didn't find anything about after extensive research is: **how to show counts **(i.e., the values provided in the `top` parameter of `vbar`)** based only on data points that are both filtered AND selected in the scatter plot**? Both the plots receive the same filters from which a view is created.

The documentation shows how to link selected points in different plots (by using the same `ColumnDataSource` object), how to filter them, and how to use `vbar`, but not all of them together.

Any hint? Thank you very much in advance.